# Removing one message from a topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

Can I delete only ONE message from a topic if I know the topic, the offset and the partition?

And if not is there any alternative?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is not possible to remove a single message from a Kafka topic, even though you know its partition and offset.

Keep in mind, that Kafka is not a key/value store but a topic is rather an append-only(!) log that represents a stream of data.

If you are looking for alternatives to remove a single message you may

1. Have your consumer clients ignore that message
2. Enable log compaction and send a tombstone message
3. Write a simple job (KafkaStreams) to consume the data, filter out that one message and produce all messages to a new topic.

Comment: Considering our event stream context, there's a fourth option that aligns more with the event-sourcing paradigm. Instead of attempting to tombstone an erroneous message, you could consider appending a new `<ConsumerNameHere>Failed` event to the end of the topic. This approach involves shifting the pointer within your consumer. The `<ConsumerNameHere>Failed` event could encompass a reference to the original unprocessed event along with a record of the attempted actions. This technique allows the consumer's pointer to progress while retaining the means to retry the problematic event :)

Comment: P.S. the above solution would only be appropriate if you wanted to advance the consumer pointer and retry at the end of the current stream, but hopefully that's clear from context.